# gráfico highcharts NO me carga

Tags: php, highcharts

cordial saludo
tengo un archivo llamado resultadosMedidas.php en el cual tengo un select option cargado por medio de una consulta con datos de años ejemplo 2016, 2017, 2018. cuando selecciono un año me deberia aparecer un gráfico que tengo elaborado en otro archivo llamado grafico.php y que es llamado mediante un script de ajax que tengo dentro del archivo resultadosMedidas.php, pero no me carga y el espacio queda en blanco. de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

```
<?php   

          $Cedula = $_POST['id_afiliado']; 
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['id_afiliado'] = $Cedula;//usando sessiones se pasa el valor de una variable de un archivo php a otro                         

          //llamado a la clase de conexion a la db
          include_once("conexion.php");

          //codigo sql para consultar afiliado por medio del id
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM afiliado WHERE id_afiliado=".$Cedula."";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);

          //imprime en pantalla nombre y apellido del estudiante
          if ($result->num_rows > 0){    
          $row=$result->fetch_array();
          echo "<div align='center'><font size=6><b>Bienvenido ". $row['nombre']." ".
          $row['apellido'],"</b></font></div><br>";

          //codigo sql para consultar los registros anuales del afialiado
          $consul = "SELECT anio FROM registros WHERE afiliado_id=".$Cedula."";
          $res = $conn->query($consul);

          { ?>

          <script>
              function mostrarInfo(cod){

              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
              else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                  document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                  }else{ 
                document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML='Cargando...';
                  }
                }
              xmlhttp.open("POST","tabgra.php",true);                  
              xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              xmlhttp.send("anio="+cod);
              }
          </script>

            <div class="container">
              <center>
                <div class="row centered">
                <form>
                  <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
                    <select onchange="mostrarInfo(this.value)">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona el año a consultar</option>
                        <?php
                        while($row=$res->fetch_array()){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['anio']; ?>"><?php echo $row['anio']; ?></option>                     
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </form>  
                </div>
              </center>
           </div><br><br>


             <center>                 
              <div id="datos"></div>                                   
             </center><br><br>



          <?php }

  }else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('SU CEDULA NO ESTA REGISTRADA'); location='../index.html';</script>";
  }
```

?>

```
 <?php 

include_once("conexion.php");
  session_start();
  $Cedula = $_SESSION['id_afiliado'];
  $seleccion = $_POST['anio']; 

  $peso=$conn->query("SELECT peso FROM medidas WHERE registros_anio= ".$seleccion."
    AND registros_afiliado_id = ".$Cedula."");
    $res = $peso;

    while ($fila = $res->fetch_array()) {
    $lista[] = $fila['peso'];
    }

    $lista = implode(",", $lista);
    $p = "{ name: 'Peso', data: [".$lista."]},";
```

?>

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">        
        <style type="text/css">
        ${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

```
    <div id="grafico" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    Highcharts.chart('grafico', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Tus Progresos'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [
                <?php
                echo $p;//, $q, $r, $s, $t, $u, $v, $x, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c;
                ?>
                ]
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Agrega  el resultado de "$p" pra probar; igual verificar la saluda a consola o algún método para ver en consola si hay error.

Comment: cordial saludo el resultado de $p seria        series: [
                    { name: 'Peso', data: [60,60,60,61,60,62,60,61]},                    ]
        });

Comment: cuando inspeccionó la página en el explorador no me sale ningun error lo único que noto es que el div está como vacío:                                                <div id="grafico" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>                          y cuando ejecuto el archivo php del gráfico de forma individual el cual si funciona sale asi:                               <div id="grafico" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" data-highcharts-chart="0">

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hn76Le30/ El resultado que te pedi de `$p` pusiste `[ { name: 'Peso', data: [60,60,60,61,60,62,60,61]}, ] });`; realmente debe ser solo `{ name: 'Peso', data: [60,60,60,61,60,62,60,61]},` la coma "," al final está de más; en navegadores web reciente no te generara error en anteriores sí no mostrara gráfico. Incluye el código Ajax que usas; breve pero entendible, donde lo delcaraste (y código), momento en que se ejecuta (donde se llama), estructura que recibes (si es resultado de invocar un php ese o que devuelve) y como manipulas esos datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para gráficas donde solo requiresactualizar los datos debes usar [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData); bajo el siguiente flujo:

1. Cargas tu página donde se mostraran los datos (inicializado o no highcharts).
2. Tu petición Ajax debe retornar solo los datos; en tu caso los valores para cada mes.
3. Actualizar la lista de valores con `setData`.

A continuación esquema ejemplo (los nombre de los archivos son para el ejemplo):

Lo que seria tu página cargada (llamemosle) **index.php**:

```
<html>
   <!-- lo que necesites de css, js, meta etc.... -->
   <script>

    function mostrarInfo(cod){

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {
                // contirtiendo a array el string
                var aValores = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                grafica..series[0].setData(aValores);
              }else{ 
                document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML='Cargando...';
              }
            }
        <!-- aquí nombro al script "buscarDatos.php" el que se llama y regresa datos -->
        xmlhttp.open("POST","buscarDatos.php",true);                  
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("anio="+cod); // corrobora o cambia según sea necesario el dato se este pasando por POST o GET como recibas en tu script php
    }
   </script>

<body
  <!-- algo de tu página -->
  <select onchange="mostrarInfo(this.value)"> <!-- tu select ya llenado --> </select>
  <!-- algo mas de tu página -->
  <!-- inicio: contenedor de la gráfica -->
  <div id="datos"></div>
  <!-- fin: contenedor de la gráfica -->

   <script>
    <!-- Estoy asumiendo que cargas datos al principio
         inicialización del Highcarts -->
var grafica = Highcharts.chart('datos', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Tus Progresos'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{name:'Peso': data[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}]
});
   </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Ahora en (llamemosle) **buscarDatos.php** *mira que en el ajax que usas así le puse para este ejemplo*; retornamos:

```
<?php
// aqui tu proceso de busqueda de consulta y transformación de datos a unos entendible para HghCharts

// $datos solo devuelve una cadena que inicia en corchetes "[" y 
// termina en corchetes "]"  conteniendo cada valor 
// por cada mes separados por coma;
// ejemplo retornado (como es cadena pongo comillas, 
// desde luego no se recibe en la respuesta: 
//         "[40.5,20.5,8,100,30,20,33,50,9,10,101,15]"

echo $datos;
?>
```

**NOTAS**

1. Las gráficas no se muestran si recibes HTML y solo lo insertas en lo que usas como contenedor de gráficas.
2. Cada vez que requieras actualizar alguna parte de la gráfica debes llamar el método que lo realiza; o si quieres actualizar todo llamar completo: HighCharts.chart(idContenedor, {LasOpcionesQueNecesitasYDatos});
3. Si estas empezando con HighChart y es solo una gráfica que estas mostrando, la llamada a `HighCharts.chart(...)`asignalo a una variable y usa esta para realizar los cambios de valores recibidos por Ajax.
4. Te sugiero uses jQuery y el [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) que dicha libreria incluye.

## ACTUALIZACIÓN

**Respecto al** *$p*: En tu planteamiento lo usas dicha variable pero directamente en el código donde llamas creas la gráficas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Highcharts.chart('grafico', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Tus Progresos'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [
                <?php
                echo $p;//, $q, $r, $s, $t, $u, $v, $x, $y, $z, $a, $b, $c;
                ?>
                ]
    });
</script>
```

en su lugar yo coloque directamente `{name:'Peso': data[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}`; para simplificar.

**Respecto a** *grafica..series[0].setData(aValores);*

Previo a `grafica..series[0].setData(aValores);` está `var aValores = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);` **aValores** contiene la conversión de lo recibido (recibido del AJAX) como cadena a Array; *aValores* es un Array de números.

Para **Highcharts** cada grupo `{name, data:[...]}` es un `serie`; (mira y veras `var grafico = HighCharts.chart('datos', {...});`) **grafico** es la variable que representa la gráfica creada; con **grafico** se hace uso de variable relacionada con el grafico en HighCharts creado; como solo tiene un `serie` se le tiene que indicar que el `serie[0]` entonces se indica que para el elemento 0 del array `serie` invocar la función `setData`; lo que esta hace es sustituir lo que actualmente tienes por lo que contiene **aValores**.

Comment: cordial saludo muchas gracias por su ayuda, yo tengo claro que con script ajax le envió un dato al otro archivo donde se realiza la consulta y me devuelve el array con los datos que van a hacer graficados. mis conocimientos en ajax son limitados me puede hacer el favor de explicarme una linea del codigo. de antemano le agradezco

Comment: grafica..series[0].setData(aValores);

Comment: en esta línea no me queda claro que debo poner ya que el resultado de la consulta que tiene el array es una variable de php la cual seria $P;

Comment: amigo muchas gracias por compartir sus conocimientos y por el tiempo dedicado.

Answer (score 0):

el código ajax que está en el archivo resultadosMedidas.php es:

```
<script>
              function mostrarInfo(cod){

              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
              else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                  document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                  }else{ 
                document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML='Cargando...';
                  }
                }
              xmlhttp.open("POST","grafico.php",true);                  
              xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              xmlhttp.send("anio="+cod);
              }
          </script>
```

este codigo toma el valor seleccionado del select option y de acuerdo al dato llama a la pagina grafico.php y debería imprimir el gráfico